# How to stop EFCore from updating a one-to-many relationship if one of the IDs provided belong to another row?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an entity `Human` that can have many `Pet`s:

```cs
[Table("HUMAN")]
public class Human
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    public ICollection<Pet> Pets { get; set; } = null!;
}


[Table("PET")]
public class Pet
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    [Column("HUMAN_ID")]
    public int HumanId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HumanId")]
    public virtual Human? Human { get; set; }
}
```

When I update a human, if I provide, inside the `Pets` collection, an entry for a Pet owned by another human, that pet will be updated and the owner will change to the current human.

Is there a way to have EFCore block updates if one of the `Pets` belong to another user?

Comment: Are you saying.. you never want a Pet to be "re-parented" to a different (parent) Human?

Comment: Not when updating a human. There could be a route that changes the human of a pet directly by the id of the pet, but adding Rex's Id to Bob's `Pets` array shouldn't remove him from Alice's.

Comment: It should raise an error instead.

Comment: Entity-Framework is "dumb".  It does what you tell it to do. (which means your data-layer should be "dumb")   IMHO : You should write business logic to check the "harmonization" rules before sending it to you data-layer.